# Tzitzit - wool or linen - in relation to blue strings

Tags: tzitzis

I'm a purist at heart so purchased linen tzitzit - of which I intended to add them to tallit of linen.  I was also going to have blue strings added, also in linen - so if you can get past my vague intro - my question is as follows:

Can blue strings be added to tzitzit if they are comprised wholly of linen, or do the blue strings have to be wool?

I came across the following which led to my question - 
quote extract - Mois Navon P'til Tekhelet - it is worth mentioning that though you may have cotton tzitzit strings, the tekhelet strings must, be halachically, be dyed in wool.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57376/759

Answer (score 6):

A blue non-wool string is not Tekhelet, much like how margarine isn't butter even though they are quite similar. Usually you can't tie a wool string to a linen garment ("sha'atnez") but here it would be permissible because the command of tzitzit overrides that. However, that only applies during the daytime when tzitzit is obligatory. By rabbinic command we don't tie wool to linen garments at all lest you come to wear it at night. (Rambam Tzitzit 3:7)

Some interpret the rabbinic command to prohibit any tzitzit on linen garments, and thus one should avoid rectangular linen garments if one can. (OC 9:6)

Answer (score 2):

The techales has to be wool, no mater what the material of the rest of the garment. (Yevamos 4b). However, one is **not allowed** to put woolen techales (or white) strings on a linen garment (Shabbos 25b, and eleswhere).

(This is actually midirobanan; midioraisa one does use techales from wool on a linen garment. But there is a concern, that one might be tricked into wearing what he thinks is techales but is really not, (think Radziner techales), or other possible concerns.)

P.S. How did you find linen Tzitzis?

Comment: Mordechai - thank you - I've learned a lot.  As for the linen Tzitsis - they were spun for me by Rivak Sari - http://rivkasari.com/tzitzits.html

Comment: That site makes a bold claim about their linen tekhelet: `How can we use linen for techelet dyed naturally from spirulina when the Talmud (Jewish code of  laws) clearly states that techelet is made with wool only from
snail hilazon dye? Answer The Rabbis do make exceptions when a person has allergies to wool, vegan which excludes animal product as apparel, Rabbis do
approve linen dyed with any other plant base dye such as sea source spiruina, but must not use kelailan the indigo plant dyes to fulfill the mitzvah of techelet.`

Comment: `One may wear a linen tallit  gadol or tallit katan who is sensitive may wear a techelet made of linen and can be dyed with any other plant base or synthetic dyes
as long as it is not kelailan the indigo plant base dye which the Talmud specifically says it must not be used. The Ramah in Orach chayim 9:2 states that at
present "it is customary not to make linen tzitzits at all." However does not state that one cannot make linen tzit zits for a linen garment. Chapter 2, Halachot 1-2
clearly states "it is best to use woolen strands for wool garment and linen strands for linen garment."`

Comment: `Therefore we do not break Torah or Halacha of Jewish
Law. This why we offer kosher 100% linen white and white with techelet blue color kosher approved naturally dyed cords.

The Torah says Techelet  must be a sea source that is why spirulina is a sea source that is plant base and kosher approved to be used for Techelet.`

Comment: Shocking am aratzus, or out right con work.